# how to add a vector of jbuttons into a jpanel

Tags: java, vector, jpanel, jbutton

I want to add a vector of 36 JButtons into a JPanel but when I do it gives me errors and say that I can't add a vector into a JPanel. Is there any way to do that?
thanks for your help.

Comment: you mean "give me the code asap" ? Hmm. well, good try, tl;dr - look up more, add code add efforts

Comment: wait, i'm confused by terminology . first you say "vector of 36 JButtons " , then you use vector separately. you want the data structure of vector">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really big on gui in java lol aside from my old school work but I found an example that should help you out. There is a difference, they used texfields and not buttons but with effort it should work out alright for you if you follow the example. The example is the third or fourth post in the thread fyi.

[link to example](https://community.oracle.com/message/8887826)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a `Vector`, so instead go through it with a `for` loop and add each individual element of the `Vector`.

```
for (JButton b : yourVector) {
    //add b to panel here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ListButtonPanel extends JPanel {

    private List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListButtonPanel() {

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        for(int i = 1; i <= 36; i++) {
            buttons.add(new JButton("Button-" + i));
        }

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 6));
        for(JButton button : buttons) {
            this.add(button);
        }
    }
}
```